# Tensorflow lite with NativeScript

Tags: nativescript, tensorflow.js, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create a mobile app using NativeScript. since the device on which this model will be running is a mobile device, it makes sense to use tflite model. My question is how to use tflite with javascript. and if that is not possible, would tensorflow.js be efficient to be used on a mobile device ??

> NOTE: I did look through the documentation of tensorflow.js and didn't find a module for tflite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a custom model through nativescript's [firebase plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/).

You will need to add the following to your firebase.nativescript.json to enable the custom model capabilities

```
"ml_kit_custom_model": true,
```

You can then add your custom model (tensorflow lite) following firebase's official [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/use-custom-models) and some additional [configs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ML_KIT.md#custom-model-inference) that needs to be done on the Nativescript side.

Comment: so there is no way of running tflite on the device itself, I have to host it somewhere

Comment: That should run on the device itself. AFAIK the firebase plugin is to be able to use tensorflow lite through mlkit (the custom model can be both local or hosted somewhere). The demo app on that repo has an [example](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/tree/816a529be7f19bad1bbd572b77835ab8e557f32d/demo-ng/app/custommodel/nutella)  showing the .tflite file bundled with the app